# TestNG Installation from Eclipse MarketPlace

Tags: testng

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3a (Release 4.7.3a).
Tried to install TestNG using below url but getting error, could not find http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What error? Do you get the same error with a newer version of eclipse?